# Should (is) be placed after (which in turn) or before?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

An iPhone X inside an iPhone 5s which in turn is inside an iMac!

Is the usage of (is) after in turn correct in this sentence?

Comment: Do not ask for help writing (or proofreading). “How should I write this?” and “is this correct?” questions are out of scope and your question may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as what meaning a word takes in context or how a particular grammar or punctuation rule works, ask that question instead. Also check out “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”, and the *[Writers Stack Exchange](https://writers.stackexchange.com/)*.

Comment: @MetaEd I am new so from next time I will keep this in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the placement of "is" after "in turn" is correct, and in my opinion that wording would be preferred to "is in turn inside an iMac," as you can tell when you recite it out loud.